# New to Java , error already

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package day1.examples;

public class String2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String x = "Andrei Vlad";

        System.out.println("Hello" + x);

    }

}
```

I keep getting this error when i run it

```
Error: Main method not found in class day1.examples.String2, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

or a JavaFX application class must extend `javafx.application.Application`
and on line error it says type mysmatch cannot convert from java lang string etc..
Thank you

Comment: How new are you to Java? If we're talking 'reeeaaally new', start with notepad and the command prompt. Did you maybe forgot to save your class after changing it again?

Comment: Well, I'd avoid notepad ;)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
[steve@newbox ~]$ cd /tmp=
[steve@newbox tmp]$ mkdir -p day1/examples
[steve@newbox tmp]$ cat > day1/examples/String2.java
package day1.examples;

public class String2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String x = "Andrei Vlad";

        System.out.println("Hello" + x);

    }

}
[steve@newbox tmp]$ javac -classpath . day1/examples/String2.java
[steve@newbox tmp]$ java -classpath . day1.examples.String2
HelloAndrei Vlad
[steve@newbox tmp]$
```

---

The most likely explanation is that you have managed to get Eclipse rather confused.

My initial idea was that this was a [homoglyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph) problem.  But provided that you have copy-and-pasted the code correctly, the evidence disproves that.

The other idea I had was that you had mistakenly created your own version of the `String` class (in the `day1.examples` package).  However, that **should have** resulted in compilation errors in the initialization of `x`.

Comment: Created a new project and it works now , old one still doesn't work thou` and same code . Edit : you were right , i created a class named "string" because I was at string examples , deleted it and it works now , Thank you. SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

The code says that there are somethink wrong with your main class but all seems ok.

In Eclipse rigth click on your projects-> run-> run configurations and check if all is ok.

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE

Comment: The problem is that all my programs keep giving the same error now , and worked just fine yesterday.

Comment: i change my post. pls check

Comment: Created and new project and it works now , dunno what was with the last one , same code doesn't work in that project

Comment: Nice!! I hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by trying with a clean of the project. Seems weird you would need to do so with only one class in a single package but it will recompile all of your code for you. Everytime I have an issue that I don't think I should have I always F5 (refresh) my packages and then clean. You'd be surprised how many issues it fixes.

Go to Project --> Clean

Then try running again.

Comment: I have like 15 classes but won't work any of them now , and worked yesterday , dunno what`s wrong, I`ll try your method . thank you